# i cant save images in sqlite database flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, dart, imagepicker

I am trying to save image in sqlite database using flutter below is my helper class
where i want to save data

```
class DBHelper{
  static  Database? _db;
  static const String ID = 'id';
  static const String NAME = 'photo_name';
  static const String TABLE = 'PhotosTable';
  static const String DB_NAME = 'photos.db';


  Future<Database> get db async {
     if (null != _db) {
        return _db!;
                     }
   _db = await initDb();
       return _db!;
                    }

 initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, DB_NAME);
    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
 }

 _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {

await db.execute("CREATE TABLE $TABLE ($ID INTEGER, $NAME TEXT)");}


Future<SaveImage> save(SaveImage employee) async {
  var dbClient = await db;
  employee.id = await dbClient.insert(TABLE, employee.toMap());
  return employee;
 }

Future<List<SaveImage>> getPhotos() async {
  var dbClient = await db;
  List<Map> maps = await dbClient.query(TABLE, columns: [ID, NAME]);
  List<SaveImage> employees = [];
  if (maps.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
      employees.add(SaveImage.fromMap(maps[i]));
    }
  }
  return employees;
}

Future close() async {
  var dbClient = await db;
  dbClient.close();
 }

}
```

> I have used image picker to pick image from gallery converted into base 64 string and save it in db.

```
selectImages() async {
final List<XFile>? selectedImages = await _picker.pickMultiImage();
if (selectedImages!.isNotEmpty) {
  _imageList.addAll(selectedImages);
}
for (var i = 0; i > _imageList.length; i++) {
  try {
    var bytes = Io.File(_imageList[i].path).readAsBytesSync();
    String img64 = base64Encode(bytes);
    SaveImage saveImage = SaveImage(id: i, image: img64);
    dbHelper.save(saveImage);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
print("selected images are " + _imageList.length.toString());
if (images.isEmpty) {
  print("no data");
} else {
  print("data");
}
}
```

> heres my init state method and a method to retrieve data from db

```
  @override
 void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
   super.initState();
   dbHelper = DBHelper();
   images = [];
   refreshImages();
   print("length of image is " + images.length.toString());
 }

 refreshImages() async {
   await dbHelper.getPhotos().then((value) {
    images.addAll(value);
  });
}
```

> i cant save image in db please help me

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Comment: So its just not adding the bytearray? Can you try with something small like just "hello world"?

Comment: okay i will try that

Comment: i tried with string "hello world" same problem !!!! in console i am getting this
I/OpenGLRenderer( 4969): Davey!

Comment: Okay, so the problem is not specifically with images, but that you're not able to put anything into the database. Im not sure that the OpenGl error is related to your app, as its general android system log. Can you wrap your db.insert in a try/catch and see if you get an error?

Comment: i have wrapped my insert func in try catch but no error has been shown in log

Comment: It's of course difficult for me to help you without the full code, so I recommend that you check the documentation and make insert work at the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing some parts in your configuration:

```dart
_onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
  await db.execute("CREATE TABLE $TABLE ($ID INTEGER, $NAME TEXT)");
}
```

should be

```
Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
  await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $TABLE ('
    '$ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
    '$NAME TEXT)');
}
```

Full working example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'dart:io';


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final dbHelper = DBHelper();
  await dbHelper.initDb();

  final bob = await dbHelper.save(Employee(name: 'Bob'));
  final john = await dbHelper.save(Employee(name: 'John'));

  final employees = await dbHelper.getEmployees();

  print(bob);
  print(john);
  print(employees);

  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: Text('app')));
}

class Employee {
  const Employee({
    this.id,
    required this.name,
  });

  factory Employee.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    final id = map['id'];
    final name = map['name'];
    if (name is! String) {
      throw Exception('Employee name from database must be a String');
    }
    if (id is! int?) {
      throw Exception('Employee id from database must be an integer');
    }

    return Employee(id: id, name: name);
  }

  final int? id;
  final String name;

  Employee copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? name,
  }) {
    return Employee(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      name: name ?? this.name,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {'id': id, 'name': name};

  @override
  String toString() {
    return toMap().toString();
  }
}

class DBHelper {
  static Database? _db;
  static const String ID = 'id';
  static const String NAME = 'name';
  static const String TABLE = 'PhotosTable';
  static const String DB_NAME = 'photos.db';

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (null != _db) {
      return _db!;
    }
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db!;
  }

  Future<Database> initDb() async {
    final documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = '$documentsDirectory${Platform.pathSeparator}$DB_NAME';
    return openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
  }

  Future<void> _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $TABLE ('
        '$ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, '
        '$NAME TEXT)');
  }

  Future<Employee> save(Employee employee) async {
    final dbClient = await db;
    final id = await dbClient.insert(TABLE, employee.toMap());
    return employee.copyWith(id: id);
  }

  Future<List<Employee>> getEmployees() async {
    final dbClient = await db;
    final maps = await dbClient.query(TABLE, columns: [ID, NAME]);
    final employees = <Employee>[];

    if (maps.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        employees.add(Employee.fromMap(maps[i]));
      }
    }

    return employees;
  }

  Future close() async {
    final dbClient = await db;
    dbClient.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much !!!!!! issue has been solved

Comment: If it solves the issue, please mark it as a solution too ;)